# Auto-derivative functions in rcpparmadillio?

Tags: r, rcpp, rcpparmadillo, autodiff

I want to calculate the derivative of the function f by Rcpp. I just found some resources in
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/StanHeaders/vignettes/stanmath.html, which use stan headers and rcppEigen. Since all my program is coded by rcpparmadillio, I'm wondering how can I access to the auto-derivative functions by rcpparmadillio and stan header(May be other AD packages).

```
 #include <RcppArmadillo.h>

// [[Rcpp::plugins("cpp11")]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
#include <RcppArmadilloExtensions/sample.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;
using namespace std;


/* function */
// [[Rcpp::export]]
doule f(arma::rowvec x){
 arma::mat yy=x.t()*x;
 double res=arma::sun(x);
 rerutn(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (currently very new) [tsetsad](https://github.com/tsmodels/tsetsad) package does this for the context of ETS ("smoothing") time series models, relying on facilities of package [TMB](https://cran.r-project.org/package=TMB). This is then used by package [tsets](https://github.com/tsmodels/tsets/) which itself uses [RcppArmadillo](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppArmadillo).

All this is fairly new and I have not had a chance to poke around much myself -- but it provides a *working* demonstration which is quite exciting.